# Handling S3 PUT notifications when writing to an Amazon S3 bucket with Hive inside Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, emr

I have a Hive script that looks like this:

Skip the header in csv when importing

```
SET skip.header.line.count = 1;
```

create CAC table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE channelAccessCodes (accessCode string,channelCode string,id string,upc string,version bigint)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "properties.channelAccessCode", 
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "accessCode:accessCode,channelCode:channelCode,id:id,upc:upc,version:version"); 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists bdc (id STRING,name STRING,address STRING,zip STRING,city_hotel STRING,cc1 STRING,ufi STRING,class STRING,currencycode STRING,minrate STRING,maxrate STRING,preferred STRING,nr_rooms STRING,longitude STRING,latitude STRING,public_ranking STRING,hotel_url STRING,photo_url STRING,desc_en STRING,desc_fr STRING,desc_es STRING,desc_de STRING,desc_nl STRING,desc_it STRING,desc_pt STRING,desc_ja STRING,desc_zh STRING,desc_pl STRING,desc_ru STRING,desc_sv STRING,desc_ar STRING,desc_el STRING,desc_no STRING,city_unique STRING,city_preferred STRING,continent_id STRING,review_score STRING,review_nr STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
LOCATION 's3://properties-uat-imports/input/BDC'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTableDeletes(ChannelAccessCode STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n';

INSERT INTO TABLE TempTableDeletes SELECT channelAccessCodes.id FROM channelAccessCodes LEFT JOIN bdc ON channelAccessCodes.id = CONCAT('BDC',bdc.id)  WHERE CONCAT('BDC',bdc.id) IS NULL AND channelAccessCodes.id LIKE 'BDC%';
```

Section - Write selected data to S3

```
create external table s3_export_deletes(ChannelAccessCode STRING)
row format delimited lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
LOCATION 's3://properties-uat-imports-emr/';
```

Writing

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_export_deletes SELECT * from TempTableDeletes;
```

It basically reads in data from a dynamo table, and a file from S3...does some jiggery pokery into an output table and writes that table to an S3 bucket.

When this Hive script runs on EMR, it writes one file to S3. I have a notification configured on this bucket to fire a message to an SQS queue whenever a PUT notification is received on the bucket. I only expect there to be one notification, but there seems to be multiple ones (6 to be precise)?

Does anyone know why this is? And is it possible to force Hive to only make one call to the S3 bucket?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I highly recommend you set the formatting around your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that the whole output commit process of hive writes files to subdirectories, then renames them, all a combination of PUT calls (one for each directory), one for each copy in the rename process.

I can't think of any easy solution here short of filtering that notification (lambda ?) to discard all but the final commit PUT